# Can Ljung-box or Breusch-Godfray be used after solving a non-linear ill-posed optimization problem?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, residuals, regularization, nonlinear-regression

I am working on solving the following CS optimization problem using the FISTA algorithm (the problem can also be solved conjugate gradient).
$$
\min_x \;||A\Phi x -b ||_2^2 + ||x||_1 
$$

Here $b$ represents my observed data (which is complex (has a real and imaginary part)), $x$ the coefficients, $\Phi$ is the dictionary and $A$ is a Fourier transform. As I said this problem is non-linear and ill-posed since $b$ is in an noisy and irregular space and it also has missing data points. That's why we are regularizing with the L1-norm.

Currently I have solved the problem using FISTA and I am obtaining the residuals from the algorithm. Now, I would like to assess my residuals and the goodness of the fit. So I was doing my research and I got to residuals analysis and to the Ljung-Box and Breusch-Godfray tests. I really would like to have a quantitative way to assess this. It is possible then to use Ljung-Box or Breusch-Godfray test after my algorithm finishes?

This is what I am currently getting. The first row is my data, the second row is my the Fourier transform of my data.

[image]

This is the autocorrelation of my residuals

[image]

And this is the PACF of my residuals

[image]

Comment: Is your data a time series? If not, there is no point in doing these tests; their results are meaningless.

Comment: @Richard Hardy They can be seen as a time series since their are i.i.d, I think

Comment: Also they are corrupted by Gaussian noise N(0,1)... So I think that even they are not a time-series per se, they can be seen as a time series right?

Comment: Moreover, I am trying to get a quantitative measure for the goodness of the fit, which means that if my residuals are just noise, then there is no signal left to extract and my reconstruction went well

Comment: I.i.d.'ness does not imply the data is a time series. Are these data points observations of the same object repeated over time? If not, it is probably not a time series. If the data cannot be ordered in a meaningful way w.r.t. time, there is no point in looking for autocorrelation and such, as it would change depending on an arbitrary reordering of the data.

Comment: Yes, this data points are observations of the same line-of-sight (object) at different wavelengths (frequency if you like), so they are ordered that way (wavelength squared).

Comment: If autocorrelation or PACF are limited just to time-series. What would you recommend me to assess and make a quantitative analysis of my residuals?

Comment: Think it a bit more I think autocorrelation at least is not limited to just time-series. Because the residuals are expected to be random noise. And that will happen not only in time-series. So I think the analysis for white noise will still be valid.

Comment: I agree that if we take an abstract perspective on this, you have a model close enough to those used in time series analysis that you might usefully apply some time-series techniques to it.  *Nothing* in the formulation of a time-series model requires that the parameter space actually be a set of times.  In this respect, your ACF is meaningful and it's clear you have substantial positive serial correlation over the first 20 lags or so.  What your description doesn't tell us is whether that's important.  What properties of the residuals matter in your application?

Comment: Thanks @whuber. That gives more confidence about what I am doing. And your question is a very good one. Since the data has been created manually (simulated) and each data point has been corrupted by Gaussian noise N(0,1). If the reconstruction have gone well and it made it to take all or most of the signal from the data, we would expect residuals close to that noise or perturbations.

Comment: That is interesting, because it suggests the serial correlation was either introduced by your fitting (reconstruction) method or by the original (non-noisy) data.  That's not surprising, but I can't say more in general.  Maybe you should be focused more on describing the actual magnitudes and patterns of the residuals to determine how they might affect your application.

Comment: Btw, the least squares above is being regularized. In that sense I don't expect the autocorrelation to be perfect as it would be with Gaussian noise. However, I would like a quantitative measure to say: "Your reconstruction (fitting) is ok. But given the autocorrelation (or some kind of test that uses autocorrelation or pacf) this can be better given this confidence level"

Comment: I have checked the standard deviation of my residuals and the numbers are very close to the standard deviation that I used to corrupt the data points. Also I noticed that as long as I take more and more data out, the reconstruction gets worst and the autocorrelation has more lags out of the confidence level.

Comment: Also, can I use box pierce, ljung box or breusch-godfray test on this data? Would that make sense since is a non-linear regression?